# how do i turn on the Keep Alive and HTTP Compression in Apache server 2.2( centos)

Tags: apache-2.2, keepalive, compression

how do I turn on the

***KeepAlive and HTTP Compression***

in Apache server 2.2(centos)

Comment: There is a cool think called "Google" that knows all of your questions. At many times its easier to search for yourself instead writing a question. Sorry for my comment but this questions is a bit to simpel.

Comment: Ya Stony... Your are right... i found what need to modified... now the question is exactly where do i need to modify(like the file name/any seeting in Apache server?". It would be of great help if you can help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

mod_deflate does the compression. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html for details.

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
```

Keepalive is in the core. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.htm

```
KeepAlive On
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for Reply... my query is "Where do i need to go and make the changes in the Apache server?"...

Comment: KeepAlive would tend to go in the global httpd.conf. The compression option tends to be done in location and directory sections. As with all things apache it depends what makes most sense for your website. Have a play around and see what works best for you.